# Картинка на фон html при разных разрешениях с наложенными слоями.

Tags: html

День добрый.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать. Есть картинка/фон (карта континентов) через body. Сверху слоями наложены надписи (названия стран). Как сделать, чтобы при изменении разрешения всё оставалось на своих местах? 
[image]

**UPD:**
Вот так сейчас у меня:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
#Layer1 {
    position:absolute;
    left:246px;
    top:351px;
    width:125px;
    height:50px;
    z-index:1;
}
-->
</style>
</head>
<body bgcolor="#aab4cd">
<div id="Layer1">Америка</div>
<table BORDER=0 CELLSPACING=0 CELLPADDING=0 WIDTH="100%" HEIGHT="100%">
<tr>
<td VALIGN=TOP align="center"><a href="../../Index.php" border="0"><img src="images/Logo.png" /></a></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="1280" height="720" VALIGN=TOP align="center">
<img src="images/map.png" width="1280" height="720" border="0" align="center" /> </td>
</tr>
</table></center>
</body>
```

Comment: А карта меняет размер при смене разрешения или она просто обрезается по бокам?

Comment: Карта меняет размер.

Answer (score 2):

```
Body{ background:url(карта); background-size:cover;}
.название{position:absolute; left:50%; margin:ставите где должна быть надпись;}
.название2{та же песня}
```

Пример грубый, в принципе, есть еще пяток способов это реализовать. Все зависит от того, как у Вас это сделано. Представите код, опишу подходящий вариант.